# opencv workon cv doesn't work

Tags: ssh, opencv

I installed opencv on my Pi zero via SSH. And now, if I digit workon cv via SSH it works.

But if I digit workon cv in a graphical session (vncserver) terminal, bash responds:

```
no command found..
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?